# Sum of values in a numeric column that are in the interval between two characters of another column (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

Having this data frame:

```
   lt  vl
1   a 1.0
2     2.0
3     0.5
4     6.0
5     7.0
6   a 6.0
7     8.0
8     7.0
9     9.0
10  d 7.0
11     NA
12    0.5
13    8.0
14    5.0
15  g 6.0
16    7.0


lt<-c("a","","","","","a","","","","d","","","","","g","")

vl<-c(1,2,0.5,6,7,6,8,7,9,7,NA,0.5,8,5,6,7)
```

I want to sum each value in `vl` between characters of `lt`. The process has to be like this:

```
a=1+2+0.5+6+7
a=6+8+7+9
d=7+0.5+8+5
g=6+7
```

To finally obtain:

```
lt  vl
a   16.5
a   30
d   20.5
g   13
```

Note: `a` is different of `a`

I'm trying hard to solve this, but it is rather difficult for me.

Comment: Your result for the second `"a"` is wrong, the first `6+7` are not in the data.

Comment: Now is corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `tapply`. The grouping factor is established with a standard `cumsum` trick.

```
f <- cumsum(lt != "")
res <- tapply(vl, f, FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
names(res) <- lt[lt != ""]
res
#   a    a    d    g 
#16.5 30.0 20.5 13.0
```